# Making a website for the iPad, removing the browser after adding to homescreen?

Tags: ipad, iphone-standalone-web-app

I noticed that if you go on google chat, and "add to home screen", once you open it from home screen, the browser disappears and all you see is the website itself... I'm wondering how google managed to do that? this is for a website I am making that is supposedly compatible for the iPad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following meta tag to the page's header:

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

The `window.navigator.standalone` boolean JavaScript property will indicate whether the page is currently displayed in full-screen mode (it will only be displayed full-screen if launched from a home screen icon, not if visited from within Safari).

Comment: how come every link to your own webpage will trigger it to launch safari?

Answer (score 1):

To keep all links from '**breaking out**' of the full-screen mode, see [this](https://gist.github.com/1042167)